# How to add extra conditions to the authentication query in Laravel using HTTP Basic authentication?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, basic-authentication

I've got a route:

```
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'auth.basic', function() {
    return Response::json(
        array(
            'name' => 'John Smith',
            'age' => 42
        )
    );
}));
```

What I want is to add `where active= 1` to the authentication query.

I know that I can add extra conditions to `Auth::attempt()` but I don't know how to do this using `Auth::basic()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to do this.

#### 1. Modify the filter and use Auth::attempt()

That's the simple way. Head over to `app/filter.php` and change the *auth.basic* entry to this

```
Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    if(Auth::check()) return; // already logged in

    if(Auth::attempt(array(
        'email' => Request::getUser(),
        'password' => Request::getPassword(),
        'active' => 1))){
        return;
    }

    $headers = array('WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic');
    return Response::make('Invalid credentials.', 401, $headers);
});
```

That's basically what the Laravel Guard class does when `Auth::basic()` gets called (except for the 'active' part obviously)

#### 2. Extend Auth

Now that's the "more elegant" way to do it. Although I don't know if its really worth it in your case. I'm also not going to describe it in every detail.

To extend Laravel Auth you can use `Auth::extend()`. Here's an example:

```
Auth::extend('my_driver', function() {
    $model = Config::get('auth.model');
    $provider = new Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider(App::make('hash'), $model);
    return new MyGuard($provider, App::make('session.store'));
});
```

The `MyGuard` class would extend `Illuminate\Auth\Guard` and override the `getBasicCredentials()` method. Finally in `config/auth.php` set `'driver' => 'my_driver'`

If you choose the second method and need more help, write a comment...

Comment: `/**
         * Call a custom driver creator.
         *
         * @param  string  $driver
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
         */
    protected function callCustomCreator($driver)
    {
        $custom = parent::callCustomCreator($driver);

        if ($custom instanceof GuardContract) {
            return $custom;
        }

        return new Guard($custom, $this->app['session.store']);
    }`
you do not have to return the new Guard. just letting you know :) . Laravel checks and does that for you. 
`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php`

Comment: You do if you want a custom guard class, no?

Comment: apparently yes..my bad :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the recommended way for extending auth has changed anyway since I wrote this post. I suggest you take a look at the official documentation or newer resources as well ;)

Comment: I guess I looked into the guard part only before. I wrote one yesterday and it works. You do not have to pass the hash, you can just pass the model. 
Damn! I just realized that the answer is a year ago. 
Basically in the most basic form this will work
   `Auth::extend('my_driver', function() {   
        return MyCustomAuthClass( new User() )
    });`
Then again if you have different model and different guard for Laravel, then that is a different case :)

Answer (score 0):

How I did it (Laravel 5.8):

Methods `basic` and `basicOnce` from SessionGuard accepts two arguments: `$field` where you can set username column and `$extraConditions` where you can set, well, extra conditions.

You can extend `AuthenticateWithBasicAuth` and override `handle` method to get something like

```
class CustomBasicAuth extends AuthenticateWithBasicAuth
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null, $field = null)
{
    $this->auth->guard($guard)->basic('email', ['active' => 1]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

and don't forget to register and use new middleware.